# Glassfish: Command start-domain failed

Tags: database, oracle, server, glassfish, oracle-apex

I have problem starting the glassfish server, i'm working on Oracle database EX and Oracle APEX, but while installing the glassfish i had a problem with the the java runtime VM, and after i fixed it, it won't recognize the JDK.
[image]
And i managed to install it though, but after i tried to start the application server, it just won't start

[image]

I had this message while installing the glassfish, and i selected the jdk file and it worked, maybe this is the problem?
And this is what i got when a tired to start the server application

Comment: Part of the error message here is missing. Can you paste the full error stack, please?

Comment: Here are the full start info, and the log file too
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/2qx8py00f5lzplb/2017-07-30-12-01-install_log_file.log)
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/2xwhwh8ny36885m/Start_Application_Server.txt)